# Any algorithm for the single value non-convex optimization problems with objective function $f(x)g(x)$

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{x} & \quad f(x)g(x) \\
s.t. & \quad x \in [0, C]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a concave and nondecreasing function (maybe not differentiable at finitely many points) and $g: \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ is a decreasing function. $C$ is a positive constant.

Is there any efficient algorithm for such a problem?